# Sort a column with Alpha numeric data in desc oder

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to sort a column in descending order using SQL query
I have used normal method

```
Select * from StaffDetail order by SerialNo desc
```

But can't able to get expected result, Sample Data for sorting given below

**Sample Data**

[image: Sample Data:]

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected Result:]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The numbers are sorted alphabetically. Which dbms are you using? Some products have numeric sensitive collations.

Comment: Can you add `BRB2017 - 6` to both sample data and the expected result?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the string into two using the combinations of `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `CHARINDEX` string functions. And then sort based on these two values.

**Query**

```
select t.[Id], t.[SerialNo] from(
    select [Id], [SerialNo], 
    left([SerialNo], charindex(' - ', [SerialNo], 1) - 1) [new_col1],
    right([SerialNo], charindex(' - ', reverse([SerialNo]), 1) - 1) [new_col2]
    from [your_table_name]
)t
order by len(t.[new_col1]) desc, t.new_col1 desc, cast(t.[new_col2] as int) desc;
```

You can also change `order by` clause like,

```
order by len(t.[new_col1]) desc, t.[new_col1] desc, 
         len(t.[new_col2]) desc, t.[new_col2] desc;
```

**[Find demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/636866/sort-a-column-with-alpha-numeric-data-in-desc-oder)**

Comment: Bro, you have misunderstood my question 'ASR2016 - 1' is a single value. I have added an image of table structure.

Comment: @ArunD : Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tableName order by columnName1 desc,SUBSTRING(columnName2,1)*1 desc
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.